# Audit: Parent entity revision on child modification (Javers/Envers/... + Hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, audit, hibernate-envers, javers

I have a kind of parent object in my application which needs to be versioned (audited), by that I mean: Every time an alteration on it is persisted, or on any of its n-deep child objects, a new revision must be created.

```java
@Entity class Document {
    @Id String name;
    // some props ...
    @OneToMany List<Page> pages;
    // getters and setters ...
}

@Entity class Page {
    @Id Long number;
    @ManyToOne Document document;
    // some props ...
    String header;
    // getters and setters ...
}
```

In the example above, if I were to change the header of a page, a new revision should be persisted for the whole `Document` entity:

```java
// retrieve document
Document document = documentRepository.findById(myBookId);
// change something on first found page
document.getPages().iterator().next().setHeader("Hello World");
// persist the document
documentRepository.save(document);
// new revision of the document!
```

I was considering using [Javers](https://javers.org/) or [Envers](https://hibernate.org/orm/envers/) but it seems none of them can do it.

Do any of you know how to do something like it on those libs? Or know of any library I can use for this purpose?

Comment: Which side is the owner because the mappings you provided do not specify that one side is the inverse (non-owner) of that relationship.

Comment: In this example the `Page`. How could the `one` side of a `OneToMany`/`ManyToOne` bidirectional be the owner?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in Javers if you map `Page` class as `ValueObject` and then if you use Shadow query. Also you should commit `Document` all the time:

```
    @Entity
    class Document {
        @Id String name
        @OneToMany List<Page> pages

        @Override
        String toString() {
            "Document $name, pages:$pages"
        }
    }

    @org.javers.core.metamodel.annotation.ValueObject
    @Entity
    @ToString
    class Page {
        @Id Long number
        @ManyToOne Document document
        String header

        @Override
        String toString() {
            "Page $number, $header"
        }
    }

    def "should treat Document as aggregate"(){
      given:
      def javers = JaversBuilder.javers().build()

      def doc = new Document(name:"1", pages: [new Page(header:"a"), new Page(header:"b")])
      javers.commit("author", doc)

      when:
      doc = new Document(name:"1", pages: [new Page(header:"a"), new Page(header:"ccc")])
      javers.commit("author", doc)

      def shadows = javers.findShadows(QueryBuilder.byClass(Document).build())

      then:
      shadows

      shadows.forEach{s -> println(s.commitMetadata.commitDate.toString() + " " + s.get())}
    }
```

output:

```
23:25:47.297 [main] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:1.0, snapshots:3, author:author, changes - NewObject:3), done in 56 millis (diff:45, persist:11)
23:25:47.315 [main] INFO  org.javers.core.Javers - Commit(id:2.0, snapshots:1, author:author, changes - ValueChange:1), done in 17 millis (diff:17, persist:0)
23:25:47.337 [main] DEBUG org.javers.JQL - SHALLOW query: 4 snapshots loaded (entities: 1, valueObjects: 3)
23:25:47.358 [main] DEBUG org.javers.JQL - queryForShadows executed: 
2019-04-08T23:25:47.298618 Document 1, pages:[Page null, a, Page null, ccc]
2019-04-08T23:25:47.275570 Document 1, pages:[Page null, a, Page null, b]
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with groovy syntax, what you mean is that I can't change a bunch of pages and commit only at the end?